# Is there a way to prefetch LOBs data in occi?

Tags: c++, clob, prefetch, occi

I'm working on a C++ application with Oracle as database and trying to fetch thousands of records with CLOB datatype.
Been searching the net on how to prefetch a CLOB datatype in OCCI but always see this "Prefetching is not in effect if LONG, LOB or Opaque Type columns (such as XMLType) are part of the query."

Is there a way in OCCI in order to prefetch CLOB or are there other alternative solutions to improve the time spent to fetch CLOB data?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to do this and we use it heavily to optimize loading tables with CLOB columns across the WAN

Instead of fetching the data as a CLOB column, convert it into a `varray(16)` of `varchar(32767)`

```
select clob_to_str_array(clob_column) from table_name;
```

OCCI will return you a `vector < std::string >` in this case.  We brought down load times from 15 minutes to less than 10 seconds with this approach

I consider this one of my best optimizations ever, but I did this only because it was too late to avoid CLOB